# Geometric interpretation of the greatest common divisor

Tags: number-theory, book-recommendation, gcd-and-lcm

In a Cartesian coordinate system,  gcd(a,b) is equal to the number of vertices (points with integral coordinates) which lie on the segment with extremities $(0,0)$ and $(a,b)$ (excluding $(0,0)$).

How could I prove it? I have an idea why this works, but it is not clear to me how I could prove it. If you could give me a proof, suggest a book or article where this geometric interpretation appears, I would greatly appreciate it.I've been searching but still can't get anything

Comment: Consider the slope of the line joining the origin to $(a,b)$

Comment: It seems that you did not formulate the statement properly. It is NOT the number of segments that is equal to gcd(a,b). The right answer is: **gcd(a,b) is equal to the number of vertices (points with integral coordinates) which lie on the segment with extremities (0,0) and (a,b), including (0,0) and (a,b)**

Answer (score 2):

The segment has the equation $(x,y)=\lambda(a,b)=\lambda\gcd(a,b)\,\left(\dfrac a{\gcd(a,b)},\dfrac b{\gcd(a,b)}\right)$ with $\lambda\in [0,1]$. So $x,y$ are integer every time $\lambda\gcd(a,b)$ is an integer.

Comment: Any book where I can consult this?

Comment: @Heriberto: this property is quite anecdotical (and elementary).

Comment: @Heriberto: no.

Comment: This is the Euclidean algorithm, in terms of segments.  So, Euclid's Book 10, according to Wiki.  

In Conway & Smith's "On Quaternions and Octonions", there's some geometric-flavored inspection of the division algorithm (Kronecker's least-remainder algorithm).  
Review/discussion of the book on John C. Baez's page: https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/conway_smith/

There's also division lattices
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_lattice